# Visual Studio 2015 giving "TS1110 Type expected." for numeric literal type union alias

Tags: typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

My general setup is this:

Visual Studio 2015
.NET Framework 4.5.2

I would like to start refactoring some client-side code from javascript to typescript. To start this process, I:

- Added a .ts file to the web project
- Let Visual Studio configure itself to compile typescript
- Installed the jquery.Typescript.DefinitelyTyped Nu-Get package `v3.1.2`
- Copied my existing typescript code into the new file

All's good except one of my type alias declarations. I made a simple demonstration of the error at the top of my file to show the issue.

[image: A type union alias between several strings is fine, but a type union alias between several ints gives an error.]

Visual Studio has no problem with a `string literal type alias`, but doesn't like the `numeric literal type alias`.

Visual Studio is reporting the version of TypeScript installed as `1.8.36.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In typescript 1.8, numeric literal type aliases aren't implemented yet, [only string literal aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-8.html#string-literal-types).

Visual Studio 2015 will let you update your version of TypeScript tools to a newer one (though not **the** newest version, since the team has since moved on from supporting 2015).

- Got to **Tools** > **Extensions and Updates...**
- Click **Online**,
- Type `typescript 3.1.1` into the search bar. That is the most recent version that Visual Studio 2015 supports as of this writing.
- Clicking download will redirect you to your browser to download the installer.
- Install away, then restart visual studio.

It should now be using the version of typescript that you installed. You can check what version it's using under **Help** > **About Microsoft Visual Studio**.

If it didn't install correctly, edit the relevant .csproj file and change the contents of the element `TypeScriptToolsVersion` from `1.8` to `3.1`.